# Get just a part of the string

Tags: c#, .net, html

I need some help with C# this time.

I have a html with this:

```
<ul class="ui_sug_list"></ul></div></div></div></form>
</div></div><div class="cnt_listas"><ol id="listagem1" 
class="cols_2"><li><a href="/laura-pausini/73280/">16/5/74
</a></li><li><a href="/laura-pausini/73280/traducao.html">
16/5/74 (tradução)</a></li><li><a href="/laura-pausini/1566533/">16/5/74
(Spanish Version)</a></li><li><a href="/laura-pausini/1566533/traducao.html">
16/5/74 (Spanish Version) (tradução)</a></li><li><a href="/laura-pausini/1991556/">
A Simple Vista</a></li><li><a href="/laura-pausini/1991556/traducao.html">
A Simple Vista (tradução)</a></li>
```

I download an html like that, it comes with no tabulation from web.
I need to print only the name of the song and the link that goes to the song.
I have no idea how to get just this information from the file.

Here's how I download the file:

```
        // Realiza Download do arquivo
        WebClient webClient = new WebClient();
        webClient.DownloadFile(
        "http://letras.mus.br/" + termo_busca + "/", @"C:\Temp\letras.html");
```

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Screen scraping is a volatile thing -- what happens when they change the layout of the site? How are you going to maintain your parsing logic? Do they provide any sort of API that might be more useful?

Comment: http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/ See that

Comment: @Cory you mean an API which enables you to download their songs ;)

Comment: @MUG4N: OP said he needs "to print only the name of the song and the link that goes to the song." Oh...  :) Disclaimer: Any advice given forth on this page is for educational purposes ONLY!

Answer (score 2):

You should definitely use the [HTML Agility Pack](http://html-agility-pack.net).

You can get your links and link values like this:

```
 var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
 doc.LoadHtml(Html);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href"])
 {
    var value = link.Attributes["href"].Value; //gives you the link
    var text = link.InnerText; //gives you the text of the link
 }
```

You could also use this class which also uses the html agility pack:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using HtmlAgilityPack;

namespace Foo.Client
{
    public class Website
    {
        public string Html { get; private set; }

        private Website(string html)
        {
            Html = html;
        }

        public static Website Load(Uri uri)
        {
            validate(uri);
            return new Website(getPageContentFor(uri));
        }

        public List<string> GetHyperLinks()
        {
            var doc = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();
            doc.LoadHtml(Html);
            return extractLinksFrom(doc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"));
        }

        private static string getPageContentFor(Uri uri)
        {
            try
            {
                var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(uri);
                var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()))
                    return reader.ReadToEnd();
            }
            catch (WebException)
            {
                return String.Empty;
            }
        }

        private List<string> extractLinksFrom(HtmlNodeCollection nodes)
        {
            var result = new List<string>();
            if (nodes == null) return result;
            foreach (var link in nodes)
                    result.Add(link.Attributes["href"].Value);
            return result;
        }

        private static void validate(Uri uri)
        {
            if (!uri.IsAbsoluteUri)
                throw new ArgumentException("invalid uri format");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 but since this is based on a live request the document can be loaded straight from the response stream (no need for a file).